# Is there a way to play fragmented mp4 at random chunk?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4, media-source

Say there is a video rendered into fragmented mp4 consisting of a number of chunks/fragments. The question is: *after the init was loaded to MediaSource buffer, is there a way to play a random fragment?*

A small research of the thing's specifications gave little understanding of the problem. Fragments seem to have a kind of an order IDs hardcoded in them. It's a fairly reasonable idea to include it in a file in case of unreliable connection and asynchronous fetching while streaming content, but is there a way *to parse a chunk and change its ID using JavaScript?*

The code below is just playing 2 minute video split into 12 fragments based on user's time and is supposed to be able to start at any chunk (not only the first) and then to repeat.

```
let mediaSource = new MediaSource
document.getElementById('video').src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
    let buffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"')
    let loadToBuffer = url => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
        xhr.open('GET', url, true)
        xhr.addEventListener('loadend', () => buffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(xhr.response)))
        xhr.send()
    }
    loadToBuffer('video/init.mp4')
    setInterval(() => loadToBuffer('video/video' + (Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000 / 10) % 12) + '.m4s'), 10 * 1000)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load fragments in a `sourceBuffer`, those fragments include presentation time stamps (`PTS`), which put them in the correct playback order in the buffer.

You can either modify the fragments themselves, for which you have to parse the atoms and change the `PTS` (and possibly other) values, or change the video element `currentTime` property, so you can play the video at that was correctly buffered.

You can inspect the `buffered` property on the video element object to check the range of time that has been loaded.